# Does docker run -v or Dockerfile VOLUME take precedence?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-image

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.7

# Deliberately declaring VOLUME before RUN
VOLUME /var/tmp

RUN  touch /var/tmp/test.txt
```

#### Observation

Now I believe I understand the implications of declaring the `VOLUME` statement before 
creating `test.txt` - the volume `/var/tmp` exposed at runtime will be based on the intermediary container prior to the `test.txt` file is created so it will be empty (hope this observation is correct)

So as expected the following `docker run` does not show `test.txt`:

`docker run kz/test-volume:0.1`

But then I tried supplying the volume at runtime as below:

`docker run -v /var/tmp kz/test-volume:0.1`

#### Question

The outcome was the same. So what does this mean? does the `-v /var/tmp`  in the docker run command map to the empty `/var/tmp` dir exposed by the `VOLUME` command in the Dockerfile and not the `/var/tmp` directory with the `test.txt` in the latest image?

Feeling a tad bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no image which contains `/var/tmp/test.txt`. The effect of declaring the volume before creating the file is that the `RUN` instruction runs in a temporary container which has its own volume. [Volumes bypass the Union File System](https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#data-volumes) so when the build saves that intermediate container, **the contents of the volume are not saved**, so they don't get persisted in the image layer.

Every container you create from that image will have its own volume, the `-v` option doesn't change that, unless you use it to map the volume to a host path.

Using your Dockerfile, you can see that by inspecting two containers. The first without the `-v` option:

```
> docker run -d temp                                                                                              
c3c4f7de411f166b3a67397ff1221552fe5b94c46bc100725a50a57231da427b                                                  

> docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' c3c                                                                           
[
    {67267d2eeb57373f76a9dd50c25f744b7d99d0a75647bf06aa0d17b70807cf71/var/lib/docker/volumes/67267d2eeb57373f76a9dd50c25f744b7d99d0a75647bf06aa0d17b70807cf71/_data /var/cache/nginx local  true }
    {91490ea73e3a9d42df9f00e32a91fe571d2143f54248071959765d5d55c23d46/var/lib/docker/volumes/91490ea73e3a9d42df9f00e32a91fe571d2143f54248071959765d5d55c23d46/_data /var/tmp local  true }
]
```

Here there are two volumes, mounted from `/var/lib/docker` on the host. One is from the `nginx` base image, and one from your image. With the explicit `-v`:

```
> docker run -d -v /var/tmp temp                                                                                  
6fa1a8713b2d6638675a3d048669943419bc7a3924ed98371771100bcfde3954 

> docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' 6fa                                                                           
[
    {9adf6954ed3e826f23a914cbbd768753e6dec1f176eed10e03c2d5503287d101/var/lib/docker/volumes/9adf6954ed3e826f23a914cbbd768753e6dec1f176eed10e03c2d5503287d101/_data /var/cache/nginx local  true } 
    {7dd8be71ce88017ffbeef249837bdd1c96c071b802a2f43b18fd406983e1076a/var/lib/docker/volumes/7dd8be71ce88017ffbeef249837bdd1c96c071b802a2f43b18fd406983e1076a/_data /var/tmp local  true }
]
```

Same outcome, but different host paths, because each container has its own volume.

Comment: Thanks for that. I feel like I had a partial understanding with the missing piece of 'volumes bypass the union filesystem'. This would mean even the final image wouldn't have the `test.txt` file as you pointed out. Goes to show why you should persist first and then expose it as a volume.