# defining resource limitation and using volumes in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, boot2docker, docker-machine, docker-registry

Is there is any option for defining resource limitation in Dockerfile?

then how to define already created volume for specific folder in container ??

I cannot using my volumes in Dockerfile , it creates new volumes with random id for each run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource limitations in the Dockerfile: no. The Dockerfile defines the steps for building the **image**; resource constraints are applied when you run a **container** from the image.

You can create volumes which contain data in the image - but you need to create the files first and then expose the volume. Build from this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN mkdir -p /var/app && echo 'saved' > /var/app/file1
VOLUME /var/app
RUN mkdir -p /var/app && echo 'not saved' > /var/app/file2
```

And the image will contain `file1` but not `file2`:

```
> docker run --rm temp  ls /var/app                                                                             
file1
```

For the reason, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741636/does-docker-run-v-or-dockerfile-volume-take-precedence).

Comment: my question is can we define particular container file is to be volumed to  host path which specified  in Dockerfile  ?????????

Comment: No, that's run-time configuration. The Dockerfile is meant to build a host-independent image - if you could specify a host path in the image, it would fail if you ran it on a host where the path didn't exist.